# Can I add npm scripts to package.json file from the cli?

Tags: javascript, npm

Like when you're already working in the cli, it would be helpful to add scripts directly from the cli, without navigating the file and add it manually.
Regardless of editing the file with bash.
I already searched npm docs and didn't find anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

`package.json` is, unsurprisingly, JSON so you could write a program which reads it, adds something to the appropriate section, then writes back to it.

`npm` doesn't have anything built-in to do that though.

You could also use a terminal editor like vim, nano, or emacs.

Comment: Yeah, I already thought of doing that. But it would be a pain to do it in every project. I was hoping there is some kind of library. Thanks anyway.